# Documentation rep re-calculation isn't updated in reputation chart

Tags: bug, documentation, reputation

In short, a while back a documentation topic I had contributed to got deleted. Following that, the reputation displayed on the chart hasn't been updated for a while now.

The chart, during the time I took it, shows my reputation standing at `17.9k` while, I have `17.4k` (colors reversed due to extension :-):

[image]

I'm using google chrome Version 51.0.2704.106 (64-bit)

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: @Neal, this happened around 2 weeks ago, I just now decided to post it. (so no, I would not blame caching :0)

Comment: Bahh Humbug @Jim Humbug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking it today, it seems that this has been fixed:

[image]