# How to deal with ignored bugs?

Tags: support, meta, bug-reporting-process

I've posted [this bug report](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339496/approving-rejecting-edit-suggestion-reinitiates-snippet) 9 days ago.

There's no real feedback, but the bug still remains. I believe it hasn't really a bad effect on our stack, but it's still a bug. So, my questions are:

- How to know if it's already taken into consideration?
- Should we have to repost them (or will they be simply marked as duplicate) ?

Comment: 9 days? That's cute. I had filled a bug report *[4 months ago](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333597/documentation-rep-re-calculation-isnt-updated-in-reputation-chart)* and it is still pending. :-D

Comment: You're joking, right? A whole nine days, for a site with the complexity of SO? This is another one of those *I demand immediate gratification right this second! I earned that badge/reported that bug/posted that flag, and I want it **now**!!!!* thing, along the lines of *I made that post that should have earned me that hat more than 30 seconds ago, and I didn't get it yet. Fix that RIGHT NOW!!!*. I've had bugs reported that took weeks to even verify actually existed and wasn't just user error or bad data. You should spend the time studying *How to be patient*. Nine days <> *ignored*.

Comment: And coincidentally, there's [this post just made](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340169/62576) that concerns not getting an **immediately awarded** hat.

Comment: @KenWhite, please, take a look in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: Posts that are written with the intent of doing what you've described are typically indicated as being suggested FAQs, so that others are aware of your intent. :-)

Comment: A bug that I really would love to see fixed is [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330228/hot-questions-are-not-that-hot-currently), ignored for 5 months now.

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard 4 months? That's cute. I filed a bug report *[28 months ago](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270153/419956)* without ever getting a response ;-)

Comment: At my work, I recently fixed a bug that was first reported in 2011.

Comment: The usual response time for bugs is [6 to 8 weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/248000)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are currently [2152 bug reports without a status-* tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug+-status-completed+-status-bydesign+-status-declined+-status-norepro+-status-planned+-status-deferred+-status-review+-status-reproduced) on MSO alone, so it could take a while before devs work on fixing the bug, if they ever get to it that is.

I believe they have an internal tracking tool to manage all bugs and feature requests across the entire network, so they don't go entirely unnoticed.

The only thing you can do is wait. If it's a really pesky bug maybe you can ping a CM or dev in chat, but I'm not sure if they'd appreciate that.

There's a great deal of information available [on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263662/can-we-have-a-guaranteed-pipeline-for-responses-from-stack-exchange) where CMs explain the challenges of improving the situation, and what we as users can do to help.

Comment: related on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263662/can-we-have-a-guaranteed-pipeline-for-responses-from-stack-exchange

Answer (score 5):

The SO team frequently patrols the meta sites and they are pretty fast to fix bugs when they see [security issues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338573/sensitive-info-disclosure), [broken functionalities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224991/unable-to-ask-a-question-on-stack-overflow), [weird layout issues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277518/all-stack-exchange-site-logos-are-showing-up-as-the-3d-printing-one) or the [mysterious butt](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89734/mysterious-butt).

However, you have reported a *minor* bug: a layout issue that happens just for a small fraction of users and in a very specific situation (suggested edits with snippets).

I'm sure the Stack Overflow team appreciates our effort to find and make good bug reports for free, but they receive too many reports daily and they prefer to focus their limited time to fix the most important ones than to give feedback to minor issues. Don't be frustrated about that. You've done a good work!

If you are interested about their workflow, take a look into this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247173/what-is-stack-exchanges-workflow-for-handling-bugs-and-feature-requests/247178#247178) from Tim.

Comment: ["If you're doing a text search in this document for the word 'butts,' the good news is that it's here, but the bad news is that it only appears in this unrelated quote." - Randall Munroe](https://xkcd.com/1942/)